# jquery .each function not working for script added html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code

```
$(function(){
    $("input[name=banner]").change(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i) {
            $('#imgtd').append('<img  class="img"  src="img' + i +'.png" alt="" />');
        }
        $( '.img' ).each( function () {
            alert($(this).attr('src'));
        });
    });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="imgtd"></div>
<input   required type="file" name="banner" class="upImage" multiple="multiple" >
```

When I select multiple images using input type file, it append images to div with id 'imgtd'. But I can't iterate these images by class name.

Comment: You need event delegation using [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Can you please explain, or please paste sample code

Comment: Have a look at the documentation first so you understand the basics :)

Comment: I just tried your code once again, and it seems to be working... What exactly you think is not working..?

Comment: Voted close/unclear: there's no expected result and actual result description, whether you get error or not is missing and [the code seems to be incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should access filename as follows:

```js
$(function(){
    $("input[name=banner]").change(function() {
      var $container  = $('#imgtd');
        for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
            $container.append('<img src="'+ this.files[i].name+'" class="img" alt="" />');
        }
        $('.img').each( function () {
            console.log($(this).attr('src'));
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgtd"></div>
<input   required type="file" name="banner" class="upImage" multiple="multiple" >
```

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < $(this).get(0).files.length; ++i) {
            var ext = $(this).get(0).files[i].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            if($.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {
               alert('file ' + (i+1) + 'not a valid image [ jpg | jpeg | gif | png ]');
            }else{

Comment: if (this.files[i]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                     reader.onload = function (e) {
                       $container.append('<img style="float:left;" class="cropimage"  src="' + e.target.result + '" alt="" /><div class="download"><a href="#" download="crop.png">Download</a></div>');
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
                    
                }
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

Here is working one:

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name=banner]").change(function () {
        $.each($(this).get(0).files, function (index, item) {
            var $currentImg = $('<img  class="img"  src="img' + item.name + '.png" alt="" />').appendTo($('#imgtd'));
        });

        $('.img').each(function (index, item) {
            alert($(item).attr('src'));
        });
    });
});

<div id="imgtd"></div>
<input required type="file" name="banner" class="upImage" multiple="multiple">
```

[JSFIDDLER](http://jsfiddle.net/f84zjw26/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$("document").on("change", "input[name=banner]", function() {

});
```

Comment: $("document").on("change", "input[name=banner]", function() { alert('sss')}) Not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over a class name using [jquery each method ][1] you can write something like this.

```
$( document.body ).click(function() {
  $( ".class-name" ).each(function( i ) {
    if ( this.style.color !== "green" ) {
      this.style.color = "red";
    } else {
      this.style.color = "";
    }
  });
});
```

Based on your code you just change the last part like this, it should work if you'referring the class name correctly.

```
 $('.img').each( function () {
            console.log($(this).attr('src'));
        });
```

Before you actually understand how does the jquery each method work see this tutorial http://www.snoopcode.com/jquery/jquery-each-method